# How to solve ImportError: cannot import name json_format in Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, tensorflow

was running a python/tensorflow program that doesn't even require json, when this message popped up - i tried doing pip install json_format, which worked fine, but did not solve the issue. This started after I implemented "import tensorflow as tf" in my code to fix another issue I was having where tf wasn't being recognized. I'm running on python 2.7 on a linux-ubuntu system.

Any help is appreciated. Below is the full error text:

```
 File "holt.py", line 7, in <module>
from tensorflow import tf


File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *


 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 91, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.summary import summary


 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/summary.py", line 41, in <module>
from google.protobuf import json_format as _json_format
ImportError: cannot import name json_format
```

Comment: Do you have the google.protobuf module? Or the Google module?

Comment: Try reinstalling with the latest version and ensuring everything is compatible with 2.7 @mike.k He definitely has the Google module with protobuf. Otherwise he would get a "No module named ..." exception.

Comment: Installing `json_format` enables `import json_format`.  But that is not the statement that fails.  Move or copy the installed `json_format` module or package into the google.protobuf directory